# Pandas: How to aggregate by range inclusion?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a "range" column and some value columns:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({
            "range": [[1,2], [[1,2], [6,11]], [4,5], [[1,3], [5,7], [9, 11]], [9,10], [[5,6], [9,11]]],
            "A": range(1, 7),
            "B": range(6, 0, -1)
            })
Out[1]:
                       range  A  B
0                     [1, 2]  1  6
1          [[1, 2], [6, 11]]  2  5
2                     [4, 5]  3  4
3  [[1, 3], [5, 7], [9, 11]]  4  3
4                    [9, 10]  5  2
5          [[5, 6], [9, 11]]  6  1
```

For every row I need to check if the range is entirely included (with all of its parts) in the range of another row and then sum the other columns (A and B) up, keeping the longer range. The rows are arbitarily ordered.

The detailed steps for the example dataframe would look like: Row 0 is entirely included in row 1 and 3, row 1, 2 and 3 have no other rows where their ranges are entirely included and row 4 is included in row 1, 3 and 5, but because row 5 is also included in 3 row 4 should only be merged once.

Hence my output dataframe would be:

```
Out[2]:
                       range   A   B
0          [[1, 2], [6, 11]]   8  13
1                     [4, 5]   3   4
2  [[1, 3], [5, 7], [9, 11]]  16  12
```

I thought about sorting the rows first in order to put the longest ranges at the top so it would be easier and more efficient to merge the ranges, but unfortunately I have no idea how to perform this in pandas...

Comment: I understand the merging logic but the new A and B column values don't seem clear.

Comment: Row 0 of the output dataframe is the summed up rows 0, 1 and 4 of the input dataframe. Accordingly row 1 is the result of the input row 2. And row 2 is the result of 0, 3, 4 and 5.